# Getting optimal email deliverability from multiple domains using SendGrid with our SaaS product

Tags: email, sendgrid

We develop, deploy and maintain a web based booking system for a growing number of clients. The web application is branded for each client, including using their own domain name in the URL that users browse to.

We send booking confirmation emails via SendGrid and want them to appear to the recipient as though they are coming from the client's domain. We have not set up any subusers yet.

Our clients tend to have seasonal campaigns that result in occasional surges of booking-related email, followed by quiet periods.

We are happy with our current deliverability and have a good reputation score.

*Assume that:*

- Our SaaS domain is mybookingapp.com.
- Client domain is clienta.com (...clientb.com etc.)
- We have control over DNS records for mybookingapp.com, clienta.com etc.

Currently, we have configured SendGrid's IP-whitelabelling so SendGrid identifies the originating server as mybookingapp.com ("Received: from o1.email.mybookingapp.com") with a From address of bookings@clienta.com.

We have got green ticks in all the SendGrid DNS settings so we know that DKIM, SPF and rDNS are OK.

I am acutely aware that the domain of the from address (bookings@clienta.com) does not match our application's domain name (mybookingapp.com). This results in mail clients like GMail showing the sender as "bookings@clienta.com via mybookingapp.com". This is slightly disconcerting for users because, until receiving the email, they don't know anything about mybookingapp.com. I also have a possibly unfounded suspicion that this discrepancy is affecting deliverability.

To meet client expectations, we are looking at options to remove all mention of mybookingapp.com from the email.

Should I:

a) Recommend we buy an IP address for every client and do IP-whitelabelling at a non-negligible cost of USD $30/month, particularly for a client that only does occasional campaigns. My research suggests that multiple dedicated IP addresses are usually used by companies with very high email volumes to keep their reputation safe and isolated.

b) Simply set up a whitelabelled domain for each client but continue to use a single IP address. My assumption is that this will cause an RDNS problem (because reverse lookup on an IP can only point to a single domain) and while eliminating the "via mybookingapp.com", possibly affect deliverability.

c) Do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "via mybookingapp.com" doesn't affect Deliverability, it only affects the user experience IF they didn't recognize the brand. I don't think is the case.

Yes, it's good practice isolate traffic and reputation, but sometimes it's not the right thing to do and the best solution is to use shared IPs.

I wouldn't suggest to buy a different IP for each client if their volume and frequency isn't high. The goal of a right setup is to find a good balance between the number of IPs and their daily volume.

Also remember that mailbox providers prefer "constant traffic" instead of IPs without traffic and sudden peaks, but those IPs need to be warmed up.

My suggestion is to assess your daily volume and the daily volume for each client, look at the domain density for providers like Microsoft and Google, and THEN decide if add more IPs, or separate the traffic.

Last but not least, you should check if you are having actual deliverability issues! maybe everything is just good this way.
Easiest and best way to know if you have deliverability problem is to check your performances by domain. Check the open rates by domain: if some is very low, there's probably a deliverability issue. If all the open rate trends are "compact" and show the same pattern, everything is fine.

Comment: Very helpful answer thanks. We have decided to stick with our current configuration for the moment and reassess in the future if there are issues with volume, deliverability or clients objecting to the "my bookingapp.com". I haven't been paying much attention to the open rates historically, but that's a good point.